# BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, operating-systems

While making partition on External HDD 
I mistakely made the HDD as Active. I forgot to remove the active mode.So while shut down there were 3 active partitions 1. C:\ , 
2.Recovery   3.external HDD.
Now when i try to boot the OS , It shows error "BOOTMGR IS MISSING. Press Alt+Ctrl+Del to restart".
Please suggest any solution.

Thanks,
Rishi.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from your windows 7 setup DVD and right before it says 'install now' click 'repair your computer'. Then you'll find options to restore the bootmanager so you are able to boot again.

You can also download a bootable partition tool like [partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html). This will enable you to edit your disks settings without booting into windows, so you can correct your mistake.

Also don't forget to select your DVD drive as the 1st boot device in your BIOS. See: http://www.windowsreinstall.com/win7/firstbootinbios/

Comment: Is there any way to do it without booting? As I am traveling it will be hard to arrange drives and all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. You can't fix anything if you can't boot into Windows. You HAVE to boot from a bootable device, whether it be your windows 7 dvd or partition wizard dvd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **boot-repair** form Linux.

- Use a live cd of linux

http://www.ubuntu-fr.org/telechargement

- Install on USB key or cd;  you can use **LinuxLive USB Creator** http://www.linuxliveusb.com/,
- Boot on the key or cd with the options of BIOS or press f10 or f8 to
  choose the boot device

more information : http://www.hiren.info/pages/bios-boot-cdrom

- Install boot repair when you are in linux : open a **console**

Past this : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

- Choose the first option

[image: boot]

- more information : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair

Good luck !